# Jakarta Servlet page not found

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm trying create servlet page with Jakarta package alternative Javax package (using Jakarta) but when I create example Servlet the code As below:

```
// Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
@webservlet("/Message")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
 
   private String message;

   public void init() throws ServletException {
      // Do required initialization
      message = "Hello World";
   }

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      
      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Actual logic goes here.
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
   }

   public void destroy() {
      // do nothing.
   }
}
```

it's work , Fine and everything work without problem but when I want use Jakarta package and change code As below :

```
// Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
@webservlet("/Message")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

   private String message;

   public void init() throws ServletException {
      // Do required initialization
      message = "Hello World";
   }

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Actual logic goes here.
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
   }

   public void destroy() {
      // do nothing.
   }
}
```

The server message 404 and not found the page, the system I use :

- windows 10
- glassFish 6.0.1 and tested with (wildFly 23)
- JDK 11

can anyone explain what happened?

Answer (score 2):

Glassfish 6.0.1 doesn't support JDK 11, probably the 6.1 will support it.
And for Wildfly, make sure you downloaded the Jakarta version, as they provide two builds: one for the javax namespace and another for the Jakarta namespace.

There are a couple of servers that support the Jakarta namespace already:

- Piranha Cloud 21.3.0: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/cloud/piranha/piranha-server/21.3.0/piranha-server-21.3.0.zip
- Jetty 11: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-home/11.0.2/jetty-home-11.0.2.zip
- Tomcat 10: https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.4/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.4.zip
- Open Liberty 21.0.0.4-beta: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/openliberty/runtime/beta/2021-03-09_1101/openliberty-jakartaee9-21.0.0.4-beta.zip
- Wildfly 23:
  https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/23.0.0.Final/wildfly-preview-23.0.0.Final.zip

Comment: I tested with wildfly 23 and result is the same with glassfish 6 thanks to reply